# How to send params in a programmatic navigation in sveltekit?

Tags: routes, navigation, sveltekit

I want to use programmatic navigation in sveltekit, sending in the same time params to the route I want to navigate to.
I know there is the ***[goto](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-navigation)*** method that I can use for *programmatic navigation* but I can't use it to also send params in navigation.

For example in vue js, it can be done like this:

```
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId: '123' } })
```

How can this be done in sveltekit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Indeed [$app/navigation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-navigation) is used for programmatic navigation, but it only accepts a string.
To create a string from params you can use a
[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object.

I've created a small utility function to generate the urls ( [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d9b0b05c38734f4fa17ee41e86e0140b?version=3.45.0) ):

```js
export default function buildUrl(path, params) {
  const query = { ...params };
  let interpolatedPath = path;
  for (const [param, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
    const replaced = interpolatedPath.replace(`[${param}]`, value);
    if (replaced !== interpolatedPath) {
      interpolatedPath = replaced;
      delete query[param];
    }
  }
  const search = new URLSearchParams(query).toString();
  return `${interpolatedPath}${search ? `?${search}` : ""}`;
}
```

Usage:

```js
import { goto } from "$app/navigation";

const url = buildUrl('/users/[user]', {user: 123, tab: 'settings'}));
goto(url); // "/users/123?tab=settings"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate via `goto`/`href` with url search params and then parse these parameters in `load` function.

```
`/your_route/?name=${userName}&id=${userId}`
```